# How to add a new field with the reference field through Mongo shell

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongo-shell, mongodb-update

I have an `address` field value inside `basicDetails`. I want that value to bring to the root field by adding a new field named `address`, so I am trying this way to add a new field address in all the documents. But the issue is the value is unable to update. I think I am wrong in syntax for referencing the value properly. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Updation Query:

```
db.businesslistings.updateMany({}, 
  {$set: {"address": '$attributes[0].basicDetails[1].valueString'}})
```

Result:

> address: "$attributes[0].basicDetails[1].valueString"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple update query cannot do complex queries such as getting the field value. You need the update query with [aggregation pipeline](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/).

The dot notation (path) doesn't work, you need the query as below:

*From inner to outer*

1. Get the first element of the `attributes` array.
2. Get the `basicDetails` field.
3. Get the second element of the `basicDetails` array.
4. Get the `valueString` field.

```
db.businesslistings.updateMany({},
[
  {
    $set: {
      "address": {
        $getField: {
          input: {
            $arrayElemAt: [
              {
                $getField: {
                  input: {
                    $arrayElemAt: [
                      "$attributes",
                      0
                    ]
                  },
                  field: "basicDetails"
                }
              },
              1
            ]
          },
          field: "valueString"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Demo @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/7FyKY4duJC2)

Comment: getting error,          caused by :: Expression $arrayElemAt takes exactly 2 arguments. 1 were passed in.

Comment: Hmmm, sounds like syntax issue from your side. Do you use the same code? Or is it possible that either the `attributes` or `basicDetails` array can be null/empty?

Comment: Created [demo](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Lj9R0fOR9ri) with the sample data mentioned, should be able to handle when the field is `null`, empty.